# Coroutines working but IntelliJ shows errors

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-js

I am working on a project using **kotlinjs** for **nodejs** and I start to learn **coroutines** and integrate them into my code to say goodbye to the callback hell.

I managed to get coroutines **working**, my code can be compiled and executed, **everything seems fine**.

...except: ***The IDE still shows me errors***. It seems to be confused by the additional libraries I added in order to get coroutines running.

I am currently fiddling around with the library dependencies, sometimes some errors go away, but then some code gets red which was okay before...

## This is what I see:

### Case 1:

[image: module dependencies in the first case]
[image: code in the first case]

> Cannot access class 'kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineContext'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

### Case 2:

[image: module dependencies in the second case]
[image: code in the second case]

> Unresolved reference: JsModule
>
> Modifier 'external' is not applicable to 'class'

You see, `launch` is recognized when I add the `stdlib`, but then the IDE complains with the other two errors.

Again, please note: **In both cases, actual compilation is successful!**

I am using **IntelliJ 2018.1** with **Kotlin Plugin 1.2.41**.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Try with 2018.2 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion If error remains, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT with sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it ...but same behavior.
I will report it to JetBrains.

Comment: Could you please share your project? And of course please report an issue.

Comment: Use only "...-core-js" version -- remove 2nd library "...-core". Don't use "kotlin-stdlib" for Kotlin/JS, use "kotlin-stdlib-js" instead (it's part of KotlinJavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ***Alexander Chernikov*** at *youtrack.jetbrains* I could resolve my problem.

I cite his explanation:

> The issue is that JavaScript libraries should be marked with special attribute to be recognized.
>   When they are imported from `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, this mark is set, so the feature works.
>   In your project they are not marked.
>
> At the moment, to correct the libs manually, please open `.idea/libraries/org_jetbrains_kotlin_kotlin_stdlib_js_1_2_41.xml` and `.idea/libraries/org_jetbrains_kotlinx_kotlinx_coroutines_core_js_0_22_5.xml`.
>   In both files find `type="repository"` and replace it with `type="kotlin.js"`.
>   Make sure IDEA sees the change. (You can exit IDEA, make the change and restart.)
>
> Then you can keep only these two libs in dependencies. The editor should work.

Here is the issue link:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24575

There I have also attached a sample project with the problem.